# Isn't stratification by orbit types actually a stratification by stibilizer types?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, stratifications

I asked this question on Math Exchange but considering the law number of people who viewed the question, I think that the question is difficult enough to post it on math overflow. I hope I am right.

Given a complex manifold $X$ endowed with a Lie group $G$ acting on it by automorphisms, it is well known that one can stratify $X$ in terms of the *connected components* of the so-called orbit types $X_{(H)}=\{x\in X: (Stab(x))=(H)\}$, where $H$ are closed parabolic subgroups of $G$. These connected components are referred to as the *orbit type strata*.

### Here is my question:

The orbit type $X_{(H)}$ can be seen as the disjoint union of all translates of the *isotropy/stabilizer type* $X_{H}=\{x\in X: Stab(x)=H\}$ in $X$, i.e. $X_{(H)}=\cup_{disjoint\\g\in N_G(H)/G}(g\cdot X_H)$, $N_G(H)$ being the normaliser of $H$ in $G$. Then every connected component of the orbit type $X_{(H)}$ will coincide in fact with some connected component of some isotropy type $g\cdot X_H=X_{g^{-1}Hg}$ meaning that orbit type strata are actually isotropy type connected components. What is then the point of talking about orbit type stratification? Isn't that simply the decomposition of a $G$-manifold in stabilizer type connected components. In many books one can find chapters devoted to the orbit type stratification, but it does not make anything new, it is exactly the partition of a $G$-manifold in connected components of isotropy types. Yet no author calls it *stabiliser type* stratification. What is the reason for that? Do I miss something here? This obvious question is nowhere even considered, let alone discussed, so I decided to give it a try on math overflow.

***Remark***: I undertook some small edits.

Comment: What you say in the second sentence of your question does not make sense to me: ``...every connected component of the orbit type $X_{(H)}$ will coincide in fact with some connected component of some isotropy type $g\cdot X_H$...''. The space $X_{(H)}$ is the (not necessarily disjoint) union of all the spaces $g\cdot X_H$, and I see no reason why its connected components should coincide with those of any of the spaces $g\cdot X_H$. Also, I think an ``isotropy type'' in the literature is a set $(H)$ of all closed subgroups of $G$ that are conjugate in $G$ to some isotropy group $H$.

Comment: Let in the following $H$ not be normal in $G$. Then $g^{-1}X_Hg$ and $k^{-1}X_Hk$ are disjoint for a given distinct pair $(g,k)\in G/H\times G/H$. Assume the contrary. Then each point in the intersection $g^{-1}X_Hg\cap k^{-1}X_Hk$ will have a stibilizer equal to $g^{-1}Hg$ and $k^{-1}Hk$. This is true only if $g=k$ as cosets, which contradict the the fact hat $g\neq k$ as cosets. In the trivial case when $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, it follows that $X_{(H)}=X_H$.

Comment: From the fact that $X_{(H)}$ is a disjoint union of translates $X_{g^{-1}Hg}$ it is immediate that each connected component of $X_{(H)}$ will sit on some translate  $X_{g^{-1}Hg}$, isn't it?

Comment: I see where your confusion comes from. Pay attention that the union of $X_{g^{-1}Hg}$'s is disjoint only if $g\in G/H$. Otherwise when $g\in G$ it would not be disjoint of course: $X_{(H)}=\cup_{g\in G}(g\cdot X_H)=\cup_{disjoint\\ g\in G/H} (g\cdot X_H)$.

Comment: In the case when $G$ is abelian, we have $X_{(H)} = X_H$. But then  $X_{(H)} = \cup_{g \in G} g \cdot X_H$ is not a disjoint union even when taking $g \in G / H$, or do I miss something?

Comment: Even if $G$ is not abelian, $X_{(H)}=X_{H}$ is still true in the case when $H$ is a normal subgroup. Assume that $G$ is not abelian and $H$ is not normal. For $g, k\in G$ the isotropy types $g\cdot X_H$ and $k\cdot X_H$ are either disjoint or they coincide completely. When they coincide, then $H=gk^{-1}Hkg^{-1}$, which implies  $gk^{-1}\in N_G(H)$, $N_G(H)$ being the normaliser of $H$ in $G$. When they don't coincide $gk^{-1}\notin N_G(H)$. Thus, $X_{(H)}=\cup_{disjoint\\g\in N_{G}(H)/G}g\cdot X_H$.

Comment: So I made a mistake. I should have said that $X_{(H)}=\cup_{g\in G}(g\cdot X_H)=\cup_{disjoint\\g\in N_{G}(H)/G}g\cdot X_H$ and not $X_{(H)}=\cup_{disjoint\\ g\in G/H}(g\cdot X_H)$.